# Add table in DocX using for-loop

Tags: c#, list, docx

I'm applications development, which has an output Microsoft word document. I use the library docx. I have a table and I need to insert the data from the List<>.

manually - work

```
Table t = document.AddTable(20,2);
t.Rows[0].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(listItem[0]);
t.Rows[1].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(listItem[1]);
t.Rows[2].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(listItem[2]);
```

I have 20 data and I do not want there to issue manually, so I tried to use a For loop, but somehow it does not work.

using For - doesn't work

```
for (int i = 0; i == 19; i++)
{              
    t.Rows[1 + i].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(listItem[i]);
}

document.InsertTable(t);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
{              
    t.Rows[i].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(listItem[i]);
}

document.InsertTable(t);
```

Here, `t.Rows` is indexed from 0 to 19, which is what you'd do in the manual way too.

Comment: I tried it, but now it throws an error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: Index , and I can not figure out why.

Comment: @Matey Check if listItem and t.Rows both have 20 elements. If they don't, set the 19 in the for loop to the number of elements in your collection minus 1.

Answer (score 1):

To make it less depend on a static row count:

```
Table t = document.AddTable(listItem.Length, 2);
for (int i = 0; i <= listItem.Length; i++)
{              
    t.Rows[i].Cells[0].Paragraphs.First().Append(listItem[i]);
}
document.InsertTable(t);
```

or use the `AddRow` function.